# Controlling the space in section numbers

Tags: spacing, microtype

I want to control the space around the dots of the section numbers (and subsection and so on). I think the space sometimes is too small like the one with `IV .` sometimes to wide, eg when it involves a `1`.

I already use microtype with pdflatex, is it possible to space the number and dots better ?
Ideally the space between  dot and 2 like in `. 2` is good and could be copied as the default length for everybody in arabic number. `II . 2` seems also good for the roman numbers. What do you think ?

[image: A]

[image: B]
[image: C]
[image: D]